# Using module pattern to run methods on leaflet map object

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to encapsulate all my [leaflet](/questions/tagged/leaflet) map functions into a [module](/questions/tagged/module), so that I can execute my map functions elsewhere in the application. All of my module's functions operate on a private variable "map", which is the [leaflet](/questions/tagged/leaflet) map object. I am running into a problem with the conditional statement that checks for the existence of a map layer object "neighborhood_polygon_layer" before adding this layer to the map, so that on reload it doesn't duplicate the layer if it already exists. The map object just accumulates duplicate layer objects but the map.hasLayer(); function never detects these objects within the conditional statement. It's as if the variable "neighborhood_polygon_layer" looses it's reference to it's object once those objects are added to the map allowing the function to execute again.

```
var sbk = sbk || {};

sbk.map = (function () {

    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', '[redacted map id]');

    return {

        render_neighborhood_polygons: function(polygonNeighborhoods, storyNeighborhoods, neighborhoods){
                var neighborhoodPolygons = [];
                var neighborhoodsIntersection = _.intersection(polygonNeighborhoods, storyNeighborhoods);
                neighborhoodsIntersection.forEach(function (neighborhood) {
                        neighborhoodPolygons.push(neighborhoods.get(neighborhood).attributes);
                });
                var neighborhood_polygon_layer = L.geoJson(neighborhoodPolygons);

            if(!map.hasLayer(neighborhood_polygon_layer)) {
                neighborhood_polygon_layer.addTo(map);
            }
    };
} ());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's as if the variable "neighborhood_polygon_layer" looses it's reference to it's object once those objects are added to the map allowing the function to execute again.

No:

```
var neighborhood_polygon_layer = L.geoJson(neighborhoodPolygons);
```

This creates a *new layer* called `neighborhood_polygon_layer` and sees whether it's in the map with `hasLayer`. This layer will never be in the map, since you just created it: layers are not === the data within them. If you want to only run this function once, either do it on initialization, create a boolean flag for whether it has run before, or don't run it more than once.